# How refresh Datagridview in VB.Net after seletc a new data

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a problem, because, when i want load a new registro in datagridview shows the same columns of the previous record with other columns of the register selected.

this is the dataselected

[image]

and this is the new data with the previus record

[image]

I tried everything but nothings works

```
        Pinicio.DataGridView1.Parent.Refresh()
        Pinicio.DataGridView1.EndEdit()
        Pinicio.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Pinicio.DataGridView1.Parent.Refresh()
```

I will explain it better, when I query an product for the first time the application works fine, but when I try to find another product where it adds the columns of the previous article along with those of the new selected product.

code for add new product

```
Consulta= "SELECT * FROM ARTICULOS AR INNER JOIN ARTICULOSLIN ARL ON AR.CODARTICULO = ARL.CODARTICULO WHERE AR.REFPROVEEDOR = '" + code.ToString + "' AND ARL.TALLA = 'S'"
ConsultaSqlDataAdapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(Consulta, Login.conexion)
                i1 = 0
                rs1.Clear()
                ConsultaSqlDataAdapter1.Fill(rs1, "TablaTallas")
                Pinicio.DataGridView1.DataSource = rs1.Tables(0)
            Pinicio.TabPage.TabPages.Add(Pinicio.TabPage2)
            Pinicio.TabPage.SelectedTab = Pinicio.TabPage2
            Frm_Buscar_Articulos.Close()
```

Comment: How are you *selecting new data*? Do you create a new query? Generate a new DataTable / DataSet / Model? Are you loading data to the same container without clearing it? Why don't you show that code? BTW, Refresh() is related to the UI element (its graphic rendering), not the data, so it's irrelevant here.

Comment: I will explain it better, when I query an product for the first time the application works fine, but when I try to find another product where it adds the columns of the previous article along with those of the new selected product, in the question have the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your complaint is that the *columns* remain

Yes, that's the way it goes I'm afraid; a DataAdapter that fills a table will create new columns as it needs to. If you then re use that same datatable for a different query the old columns will remain (and be empty)

`Clear()` removes *rows*, not *columns*

I suggest you make a new table: it's the simplest way:

```
            Consulta= "SELECT * FROM ARTICULOS AR INNER JOIN ARTICULOSLIN ARL ON AR.CODARTICULO = ARL.CODARTICULO WHERE AR.REFPROVEEDOR = @c AND ARL.TALLA = 'S'"
            ConsultaSqlDataAdapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(Consulta, Login.conexion)
            ConsultaSqlDataAdapter1.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  code.ToString() ' change 50 to the width of your column
            i1 = 0
            Dim dt as New DataTable 
            ConsultaSqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt)
            Pinicio.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Please note also I have fixed your sql injection hacking prone sql. Never again write an SQL where you string concatenate a value into it. Always use parameters. See http://Bobby-tables.com

Use `&` to concatenate strings in VB, not `+`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it and I will review the sql injection.

Comment: Most welcome! Maybe check out Dapper or strongly typed datasets, they can cut out a lot of this tedious low level code

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to touch the grid. It will just display whatever is in its data source. You should be populating a `DataTable` and binding that to the grid via a `BindingSource`. To "refresh" the data, simply repopulate the same `DataTable`. Everything else will take care of itself. You might want to call `SuspendBinding` and `ResumeBinding` on the `BindingSource` at start and finish if you intend to clear the `DataTable` before repopulating.

Answer (score 0):

you should clear the datagridview first

```
Pinicio.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
Pinicio.dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

The Refresh is only nneded if you don't add new rows